# How to control how many cells are triggered in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

If I have column A receive 1000 rows of input and column B has some function that takes column A cells as input for some custom function. How do I control how many cells in column B can run at a time? For example
Column A receives input into rows 1-1000. Column B has rows 1-5 trigger. In order words, how to setup concurrency control for columns?

Edit: Referring to the picture - I will paste in 1000 cells of data into column A. I need column B to only process `X` rows/cells at a time.

[image: sample sheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 I added some details + picture

Answer (score 0):

based on your picture... if you want to process only 20 rows out of 1000 you could maybe try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FUNCTION(A1:A20))
```

ofc if your Function supports the ArrayFormula variation

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I like this comment. this should be posted as answer

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but just for reference, column B has a custom Apps Script function that calls a third-party API (which is why I need to throttle the amount of rows being triggered) @player0

Comment: So do you basically want to only call a certain amount of functions in column B without calling the rest? And all your functions in column B are Apps Script function calls?

Comment: Yeah I only want to call a certain amount of functions at a time - eventually I need all of them to run though @MateoRandwolf

Comment: Are you intending to use **Apps Script** for this? If so, how have you linked an Apps Script function to your cell? Or are you just using in column B Google Sheets [Formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)?